# Email last failed NAnt Target using CruiseControl.NET email publisher?

Tags: xslt, cruisecontrol.net, nant, cruisecontrol

Since I am using CruiseControl to handle failed and successful build messages, I thought it would neat to have it email just the last failed target rather than emailing the entire failed build logs. I believe this might be handled in the **NAnt.xsl** file but unsure how to accomplish this. Any ideas?

Comment: To test your theory just edit NAnt.xsl and see if it has any effect on the emails. You may have to restart cruisecontrol.net after each change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a for each loop in the xsl to get the last target worked perfectly `<xsl:if test="position()=last()">`